# reorder columns based on values in a particular row.

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have the following data in a dataframe:

```
  aa bb  cc
1 3 4 5
2 5 4 3
3 7 8 6 
..
100 33 63 55
```

I need to reorder the columns based on the values in the last row. The result of this transformation would be:

```
  bb  cc  aa
1 4  5  3
2 4  3  5 
3 8  6  7
...
100 63 55 33
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
x <- structure(list(aa = c(3L, 5L, 7L, 33L), bb = c(4L, 4L, 8L, 63L),
  cc = c(5L, 3L, 6L, 55L)), .Names = c("aa", "bb", "cc"),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "100"))
x[,order(-x[nrow(x),])]
```

Comment: Thanks, can u pl explain what -x[nrow...] is doing

Comment: `x[nrow(x),]` returns the last row... `-x[nrow(x),]` is the opposite, so it sorts in the order you want.  You could have used `x[,order(x[nrow(x),],decreasing=TRUE)]` instead, but I prefer less typing. :)

Answer (score 3):

Building on Joshua Ulrich's answer, in case you want to sort by the **row name**, rather than number:

```
x[, order(-x[which(rownames(x) == '100'), ]) ]
```

where `100` is the row name, as in the example above.