# Reorder Columns in a df based on row values

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a df with this structure:

```
id v1 v2 v3
1  1  2  3
2  4  4  1
3  1  1  1
```

And would like to reorder columns based on the values of the first row like so:

```
id v3 v2 v1
1  3  2  1
2  1  4  4
3  1  1  1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reorder columns based on values in a particular row.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147372/reorder-columns-based-on-values-in-a-particular-row)

Answer (score 1):

We subset the first row without the first column, `unlist`, `order` on descending, then add 1, concatenate the index of first column to do the reordering

```
df1[c(1, 1 + order(-unlist(df1[1, -1])))]
```

-output

```
#  id v3 v2 v1
#1  1  3  2  1
#2  2  1  4  4
#3  3  1  1  1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, v1 = c(1L, 4L, 1L), v2 = c(2L, 4L, 1L
), v3 = c(3L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```